# Tedious issue with comparing dates through Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Today I faced with the problem of comparing two dates using GAS: `currentDate` contains todays date and `scheduledDate` contains dates put in the column which is determined as `row[3]`.

I've already spent on it 5 hours (hope that I was unlucky) and before we start the first thing to describe here is how cells in `scheduledDate` are filled: using custom function (code is put below) `=SubtractDaysFromDate('2016'!A54, 8)`, it subtracts `8` days from date located in `'2016'!A54` and shows an outcome in a cell as `08/07/2016` or `08.07.2016` (depends on how you set up viewing format).

Here is the `=SubtractDaysFromDate()` source code:

```
function SubtractDaysFromDate(date, d) {
  var output = new Date(date.getTime()-d*(24*3600*1000)); // d — количество вычитаемых дней, date — дата или ячейка с датой, из которой вычитается данное количество дней.
  return output;
}
```

Here is the source code of my script:

```
function SendElectronicMailing() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = "Рассылка"; // Здесь указывается название листа в таблице.
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var startRow = 2; // Здесь первая строка для отправки рассылки.
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; // Здесь количество строк, которые необходимо обработать для отправки рассылки.
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
/* Здесь переменные с тематическими рассылками. */
var mailingChildrenHealth = "Здоровье детей перед отдыхом";
var mailingNonPersonalized = "–";
/* Здесь переменные со статусами электропочтовых рассылок. */
var statusMailingAwaiting = "Рассылка ожидает отправки";
var statusMailingSent = "Рассылка отправлена";
var statusMailingNotRequired = "Рассылка не требуется";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var scheduledDate = new Date(row[3]); // Здесь указывается столбец с назначенной датой для отправки электропочтовой рассылки.
    var formattedCurrentDate = Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
    Logger.log(currentDate);
    var formattedScheduledDate = Utilities.formatDate(scheduledDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
    Logger.log("Getting new Date(): " + scheduledDate);
    Logger.log("Getting plain row[3]: " + row[3]);
    Logger.log("Using toString() and after replace(): " + row[3].toString().replace(/\./g, "/"));
    Logger.log("Using valueOf() of row[3]: " + scheduledDate.valueOf());
    var bookingNumber = [i+2];
    var contactFullName = row[0];
    var contactGivenName = contactFullName.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
    var contactEmail = row[1];
    var mailingTopic = row[2];
    var cheapTicketsFinderLink = "http://go.ruslanchik.ru/";
    var mailingStatus = row[4]; // Столбец, в котором выставляется статус отправки/неотправки писем электропочтовой рассылки.
    var senderName = "Наталья Селецкая (Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56)";
    var replyTo = "natalya@berdyanskaya56.ru";
    Logger.log(formattedCurrentDate + " ==? " + formattedScheduledDate);


        /* Выставление статуса «Рассылка не требуется» для бронирований, по которым ввиду своего скудоумия не смог настроить отправку рассылки. */
        if (currentDate.valueOf() > scheduledDate.valueOf() && mailingStatus == statusMailingAwaiting) {
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(statusMailingNotRequired);
        Logger.log("Выставлен статус " + "«" + statusMailingNotRequired + "»" + " электропочтовой рассылки для бронирования № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " по причине несвоевременности её отправки гостю.");
        }

        /* Тематическая рассылка для гостей с детьми («забота о здоровье детей») с общей рассылкой о дешёвых билетах в Ейск и обратно. */
        if (formattedCurrentDate == formattedScheduledDate && mailingTopic == mailingChildrenHealth && mailingStatus == statusMailingAwaiting) {
        /* Здесь рассылка о здоровье детей перед отдыхом. */
        var subject_children_health = "Email subject";
        var message_children_health = "Email body.";
        MailApp.sendEmail(contactEmail, subject_children_health, message_children_health, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
        /* Здесь рассылка о дешёвых билетах в Ейск и обратно для гостей с детьми. */
        var subject_cheap_tickets = "Email subject";
        var message_cheap_tickets = "Email body";
        MailApp.sendEmail(contactEmail, subject_cheap_tickets, message_cheap_tickets, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
        /* А здесь уже проставление статуса отправки. */
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(statusMailingSent);
        Logger.log("Отправлены тематическая и общая электропочтовые рассылки для бронирования № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " гостю на " + contactEmail + ".");
        }
        SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Здесь завершается обновление ячеек 5-го столбца, в котором проставляется статус отправки электропочтовых рассылок гостям.
  }
}
```

*To check inputs*, going to the link above you can check sheets named as `2016` (from this sheet `=SubtractDatesFromDate()` gets dates to subtract from) as well as `Рассылка` (on this sheet my script is run).

To continue with, my script goes through all cells with these subtracted dates (`=SubtractDaysFromDate()`) on the sheet called `Рассылка` and checks whether current date is equal to the `scheduledDate` (i.e., a column containing all cells with `=SubtractDaysFromDate()` on this sheet) and then sends emails.

The problem is that while a small part of dates in `scheduledDate` (resulted by `=SubtractDaysFromDate()`) is correctly recognised, another part of them stays to be not recognised and retrieved as `01.01.1970`.

To illustrate the problem, here is the script log:

```
[16-07-08 14:31:40:171 EAT] 08.07.2016 ==? 01.01.1970
[16-07-08 14:31:40:172 EAT] Fri Jul 08 14:31:40 GMT+03:00 2016
[16-07-08 14:31:40:173 EAT] Getting new Date(): Fri Jun 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:173 EAT] Getting plain row[3]: Fri Jun 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:174 EAT] Using toString() and after replace(): Fri Jun 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:175 EAT] Using valueOf() of row[3]: 1464901200000
[16-07-08 14:31:40:175 EAT] 08.07.2016 ==? 03.06.2016
[16-07-08 14:31:40:176 EAT] Fri Jul 08 14:31:40 GMT+03:00 2016
[16-07-08 14:31:40:177 EAT] Getting new Date(): Wed Aug 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:178 EAT] Getting plain row[3]: Wed Aug 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:178 EAT] Using toString() and after replace(): Wed Aug 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:179 EAT] Using valueOf() of row[3]: 1470171600000
[16-07-08 14:31:40:179 EAT] 08.07.2016 ==? 03.08.2016
[16-07-08 14:31:40:181 EAT] Fri Jul 08 14:31:40 GMT+03:00 2016
[16-07-08 14:31:40:181 EAT] Getting new Date(): Invalid Date
[16-07-08 14:31:40:182 EAT] Getting plain row[3]: #ERROR!
[16-07-08 14:31:40:182 EAT] Using toString() and after replace(): #ERROR!
[16-07-08 14:31:40:183 EAT] Using valueOf() of row[3]: NaN
[16-07-08 14:31:40:183 EAT] 08.07.2016 ==? 01.01.1970
```

If you look through the code above, it is clear that while for some dates comparison works perfectly:

```
[16-07-08 14:31:40:176 EAT] Fri Jul 08 14:31:40 GMT+03:00 2016 (note: this a current date)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:177 EAT] Getting new Date(): Wed Aug 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:178 EAT] Getting plain row[3]: Wed Aug 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:178 EAT] Using toString() and after replace(): Wed Aug 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:179 EAT] Using valueOf() of row[3]: 1470171600000
[16-07-08 14:31:40:179 EAT] 08.07.2016 ==? 03.08.2016
```

For other part of them it doesn't:

```
[16-07-08 14:31:40:181 EAT] Fri Jul 08 14:31:40 GMT+03:00 2016 (note: this a current date)
[16-07-08 14:31:40:181 EAT] Getting new Date(): Invalid Date
[16-07-08 14:31:40:182 EAT] Getting plain row[3]: #ERROR!
[16-07-08 14:31:40:182 EAT] Using toString() and after replace(): #ERROR!
[16-07-08 14:31:40:183 EAT] Using valueOf() of row[3]: NaN
[16-07-08 14:31:40:183 EAT] 08.07.2016 ==? 01.01.1970
```

*For better undestanding* here is a link to my GS sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1azDfWZWDSVTVVKLaJZlsRDbW21-Cps8Hx8M2kbclw-g/edit?pli=1#gid=2147296153.

Please, could you check if I miss anything important to make it work properly? Why one part of dates calculated by `=SubtractDatesFromDate()` is recognised correctly by my script, another and the biggest part of them is not?

How can I fix it? All result-oriented attempts to solve this issue are strongly appreciated.

---

**Edited.** It is a part of my code that I've already edited:

```
function SendElectronicMailing1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var bookingsSheetName = "2016"; // Здесь указывается название листа откуда брать даты заезда по бронированиям.
var mailingSheetName = "M1"; // Здесь указывается название листа где обновлять статусы отправки электропочтовой рассылки.
var bookingsTableSheet = ss.getSheetByName(bookingsSheetName);
var mailingListSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mailingSheetName);
var startRow = 2; // Здесь первая строка для отправки рассылки.
var bookingsNumRows = bookingsTableSheet.getLastRow()-1; // Здесь количество строк, которые необходимо обработать для отправки рассылки.
var mailingNumRows = mailingListSheet.getLastRow()-1;
var bookingsDataRange = bookingsTableSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, bookingsNumRows, 2);
var mailingDataRange = mailingListSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, mailingNumRows, 6);
var bookingsData = bookingsDataRange.getValues();
var mailingData = mailingDataRange.getValues();
/* Здесь переменные с тематическими рассылками. */
var mailingChildrenHealth = "Здоровье детей перед отдыхом";
var mailingNonPersonalized = "–";
/* Здесь переменные со статусами электропочтовых рассылок. */
var statusMailingAwaiting = "Рассылка ожидает отправки";
var statusMailingSent = "Рассылка отправлена";
var statusMailingNotRequired = "Рассылка не требуется";
  for (var i = 0; i < bookingsData.length; ++i) {
    var row = bookingsData[i];
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var scheduledDate = new Date(row[0]).setHours(0,0,0,0)+(-10*24*3600*1000); // Здесь указывается столбец с назначенной датой для отправки электропочтовой рассылки. Её еще можно считать через new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)+(-10*24*3600*1000).
    var formattedCurrentDate = Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
    Logger.log("It is a current date: " + currentDate);
    var formattedScheduledDate = Utilities.formatDate(scheduledDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
    Logger.log("Getting new Date() of row " + [i+2] + ": " + scheduledDate);
    Logger.log("Getting clear value of row " + [i+2] + ": " + row[3]);
    Logger.log("Using toString() and after replace(): " + [i+2] + ": " + row[3].toString().replace(/\./g, "/"));
    Logger.log("Using valueOf() of row " + [i+2] + ": " + scheduledDate.valueOf());
    var bookingNumber = [i+2];
    var contactFullName = row[0];
    var contactGivenName = contactFullName.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
    var contactEmail = row[1];
    var mailingTopic = mailingData.row[2];
    var cheapTicketsFinderLink = "http://go.ruslanchik.ru/";
    var mailingStatus = row[4]; // Столбец, в котором выставляется статус отправки/неотправки писем электропочтовой рассылки.
    var senderName = "Наталья Селецкая (Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56)";
    var replyTo = "natalya@berdyanskaya56.ru";
    Logger.log(formattedCurrentDate + " ==? " + formattedScheduledDate);
}
}
```

Mu question is how to get the values of `row[2]` in the sheet `Рассылка` and write it to variable placed in `for (var i = 0; i < bookingsData.length; ++i) {` linking to `2016`? Will it be a proper way to use `var mailingTopic = mailingData.row[2];`?

Comment: If a spreadsheet contains a date that's recognized by it as a date, the methods getValue/getValues will return a date object for that cell, not a string. You don't need to call `new Date()` on that: use `var scheduledDate = row[3];`

Comment: @Bookend, Please check the logs from the description above. On `Logger.log("Getting clear value of row " + [i+2] + ": " + row[3]);` it returns `[16-07-08 19:23:54:543 EAT] Getting clear value of row 54: #ERROR!`.

Comment: @Bookend, It doesn't even read it for an unknown reason (as for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty dumb, and may not fix the problem, however, I found that GAS is sometimes very finicky. It's normally something I would do just as a throwaway, but since I can't edit the script myself...

Try moving the left '(' so it is around the d. I know order of operations SHOULD handle this, but it may not, then you would be having a serious issue. And I can't think of what else would cause the problem on only some dates, unless the dates in the spreadsheet were incorrectly formatted, which they don't seem to be. So, instead of this:

```
var output = new Date(date.getTime()-d*(24*3600*1000));
```

try:

```
var output = new Date(date.getTime()-(d*24*3600*1000));
```

EDIT:

This obviously is not EXACTLY what your after, but it shows transferring cells between two sheets on the same SS.

```
function example() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet2');

  var startRow = 1;
  var numRows = sheet1.getLastRow()-1; 
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var row = []

  for (var i in data) {
    row.push(data[i] + 10);
  }

  sheet2.appendRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Let's try it. Please wait a moment for a post update.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't help: `[16-07-08 18:31:06:783 EAT] Getting new Date() of row 54: Invalid Date`.

Comment: What date are you getting an error on? Is it ticking months down properly? Or is it going into negative numbers for the date?

Comment: It retrieves an error for all dates starting from row № 16. All the dates are the same. I just subtract 10 days from each date. All to months display properly starting with zero if it is a two-digit month (for example, `07`).

Comment: Alright, I think that must be what's happening. Try changing the date in row 12 to 09.06.16, see if you get an error at that row.

Comment: Here it is sir: `[16-07-08 08:51:05:520 PDT] Getting new Date() of row 12: Thu Jun 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)`.

Comment: I just was thinking if I could connect the clear dates from the list `2016` without using `=SubtractDatesFromDate()` and just subtract this number of days in the same script? What I mean to say is don't use extra column on `Рассылка` (with those dates by `=SubtractDatesFromDate()`) sheet but rather to calculate the subtracted date in my full script. But how can I connect two sheets in one script to input values of sheet `2016` and to output changes on sheet `Рассылка`?

Comment: Does your script run on open? Or do you have to click something to get it running? (The part logging information)

Comment: No, I run it manually by pressing a button in self-created tab menu.

Comment: I think your last suggestion would likely be best then. I'm at a loss for what could be wrong, unless it's a problem on the Google side, or I'm blind.                                                             

To get it to intake from one sheet and output to another, just open both of them using spreadsheetApp.openBy...('...'), and put them to two separate vars.                                                                                                       

Then var input.getRows (or whatever)                                                  
var output.addCell (or whatever)

Comment: Please, can you give an example by updating your post? I have two sheets. I would like to use `2016` for input data and `Рассылка` to change cells. Using my existing source, how should I implement it? If I write `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {` it only determines the range of sheet `Рассылка`, not the range of `2016`. I only need `row[0]` from `2016`.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I refer to the column in "Рассылка" adding variables in 'for (var i = 0; i < bookingsData.length; ++i) {` which refers to `2016`?

Comment: Or could I just using this `var mailingTopic = mailingListSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3);`?

Comment: I would just fiddle with it until it works exactly how you want, now that you have the general method. Here's the reference for sheet operators: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet